# Unknown statements in script

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Wrote script in ORACLE APEX, it said that "You have requested to run a script containing unknown statement(s). Please remove the following statement(s)." What is wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE deptno_seq INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 50 MAXVALUE 90; /

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER task1_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON dept
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :new.deptno IS NULL THEN
        :new.deptno := deptno_seq.nextval;
    END IF;

    IF :new.loc IS NULL THEN
        :new.loc := 'MOSCOW';
    END IF;

END; /

INSERT INTO dept (DNAME) VALUES('MARKETING'); /
INSERT INTO dept (DNAME, LOC) VALUES('SPORT', 'LONDON'); /

SELECT * FROM dept; /

ALTER TRIGGER task1_trigger DISABLE; /
```

Error: https://i.ibb.co/CV1ZgfG/error.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of those slashes shouldn't be there, and the one that should is in the wrong place.  Should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE deptno_seq INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 50 MAXVALUE 90;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER task1_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON dept
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :new.deptno IS NULL THEN
        :new.deptno := deptno_seq.nextval;
    END IF;

    IF :new.loc IS NULL THEN
        :new.loc := 'MOSCOW';
    END IF;

END; 
/

INSERT INTO dept (DNAME) VALUES('MARKETING');
INSERT INTO dept (DNAME, LOC) VALUES('SPORT', 'LONDON');

SELECT * FROM dept;

ALTER TRIGGER task1_trigger DISABLE;
```